# Why xmonad does not see any application included in users $PATH variable?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, xmonad, mx-linux

I have recently installed `MX Linux` on my laptop `XFCE` ahs version. Along that I have installed `xmonad`. The problem is xmonad does not see any scripts or application that are included in my `$PATH` variable. Same configuration works fine on my Debian machine what reason for such behaviour? Same thin happens with `rofi`, it sees all application from `/usr/local/bin` but none from `$PATH`.

Could not find any information on that in google...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because a user's $PATH is likely being set by the shell's interactive config file like bash's .bashrc. This would not be included in the $PATH for a program like xmonad as it would be started by something like the display manager. You likely need to modify the path in ~/.profile

Comment: I figured it was due to some syntax errors in my .profile